# asp.net mvc: simulating autopostback for simple checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple checkbox, generated with:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("myCB" )%>
```

How can I add an onChange handler to this that does a submit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an onClick handler to the CheckBox that submits the form the CheckBox belongs to...quick, clickHandler codeless example:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("myCB", 
    new { onClick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();" });
```

(example definitely not checked for accuracy)

Comment: If this code should work, the checkbox has to be right beneath the `form`. Use: `$(this).parents('form:first').submit();` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one form, and are not using JQuery (you should be, by the way) try this:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("myCB", 
new { onClick = "document.form.submit();" });
```

Comment: This is close, the actual syntax is document.forms[0].submit()

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using jQuery to support this because it makes it easier to add the behavior to a checkbox throughout your site by having the selector either be ID or class-based.  Then you could put the script anywhere on the page or in an external .js file.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $('#myCB').click(function() { $(this).parent('form:first').submit(); });
</script>
```

Alternatively, the selector could be class-based (or any attribute for that matter).  More info here: `http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors`

Comment: I'll probably end up using this on other projects, but for now it's just one place - thanks, though.