# How can I make an asp.net mvc checkbox trigger an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I would like to update the database when someone checked a box that represents a bit field on the row.  I have been going off of this question: [Ajax.ActionLink(...) with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139920/ajax-actionlink-with-checkbox)
Here is my code in the cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Macro_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Claimed, new { id = item.Macro_Name, data_url = Url.Action("ToggleClaim", "MacroStatus")})
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Claimed)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Finished)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Completed)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Macro_Name }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Macro_Name }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Macro_Name })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

In the MacroStatusController class I have the following action:

```
    public ActionResult ToggleClaim(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        MacroStatus macroStatus = db.MacroStatus1.Find(id);
        if (macroStatus == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            macroStatus.Date_Claimed = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(macroStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

However, ToggleClaim isn't running when I check or uncheck the box.  There are no compile errors.  This is my first try with asp.net mvc, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `data-url` attribute only contains some url now. There needs to be some piece of Javascript that uses it.

Comment: There are a ton of ways to approach this, but you need something to do an AJAX call to a server endpoint (probably a Web API method, since you're using ASP.net MVC) when you check that box.  The "quick and dirty" answer is to use a jQuery selector for you checkbox and register a function using $([selector]).change(function(){});  You could also bind the checkbox to a kendo viewmodel function, or any number of other approaches.

Comment: You could look here, too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784412/asp-net-mvc-simulating-autopostback-for-simple-checkbox

Comment: @EricBurcham The key point is sending an ajax request when checkbox changed.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I thought that was clear in my comment, but you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @EricBurcham Yes it's clear in your comment. I think having an answer is more useful than leaving comment. unfortunately I didn't read your comment  but as I see now your comment is good as answer :) I edited the answer and mentioned you:) Hope you find it helpful or let me know if you prefer to post your own answer:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need ajax for this.
First, add a class to the checkboxes so you will have a hook to attach your click event.

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Claimed, new { id = item.Macro_Name, @class = "toggle" data_url = Url.Action("ToggleClaim", "MacroStatus")})`

Now add your javascript.

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.toggle').change(function() {
                var self = $(this);
                var url = self.data('url');
                var id = self.attr('id');
                var value = self.prop('checked');

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { id: id },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: , class = "toggle" is giving me a syntax error here.  Is that a valid keyword here?

Comment: Sorry, class is a reserved word, escape it with @ - `@class = "toggle"`

Comment: hi how to *update the row upon Ajax success/fail*. For e.g. if `Status` was a col in the row. And if Approved/Rejected was a radio button with some notes, so if I want to -- toggle the color of the row, and update the value of status in the row.

Answer (score 3):

The key point is sending an ajax request when checkbox changed.

As mentioned in comments by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406732/eric-burcham), You can trigger that action using many different ways. for example, put this script in your codes:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#Claimed').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ToggleClaim/MacroStatus/@item.Macro_Name',
                cache: false,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) { alert('success'); },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And correct checkbox code this way:

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Claimed)
</td>
```

The above code, triggers the action each time you check or uncheck the checkbox, you can simply check if the checkbox is checked and then send ajax request.

Comment: @EricBurcham Thank you:)

Comment: To pass the correct macro name like you are trying to do, you would have to put this inside the foreach loop. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @JB06 Which macro name? Which loop? Do what? ;)

Comment: Your url string won't work unless you put this inside the foreach, how else would you use @item?

Comment: Very good point! I have never seen that loop yet;) And this way I should not use Id too!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when **checkbox** is unchecked & form is submitted; no form field related to checkbox is `submitted`. You either have to use JavaScript to add `hidden` variable as described in [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked), or make a Ajax hit when checkbox is checked. [jQuery Ajax checkbox state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117673/jquery-ajax-checkbox-state)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without script using fontawesome and a anchor with a standard controller.

Add a link to the css file in your layout page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css"           
integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In your view or display template add an anchor

```
<a asp-controller="MacroStatus" asp-action="ToggleClaim" asp-route- 
id="item.Macro_Name">
@if (item.Claimed)
{
    <span class="fas fa-toggle-on fa-2x"></span>
}
else
{
    <span class="fas fa-toggle-off fa-2x"></span>
}
</a>
```

It looks like a checkbox and is clickable and is also great if you have multiple instances in one view, for example if you are using a display template for an array of objects.

The above can be made very clean and re-usable by using a component for the toggle on/off part.

```
<vc:toggle-on-off toggle="@item.Claimed"></vc:toggle-on-off>
```

Then it would look something like:

```
<a asp-controller="MacroStatus" asp-action="ToggleClaim" asp-route- 
id="item.Macro_Name">
    <vc:toggle-on-off toggle="@item.Claimed"></vc:toggle-on-off>
</a>
```